# Thread Safe Queue Deadlocks

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-safety, locking

I have written a thread safe queue which gives deadlock error. I am unable to figure out reason. I modified the functions to use local locks, instead of member-variable lock. Then, it seems to run fine.

Code:

```
template <typename T>
class MyQueue {
queue<T> arr;

mutex mtx;
unique_lock<mutex> lck;
condition_variable cv;
public:
MyQueue() {
    lck = unique_lock<mutex>(mtx, defer_lock);
}

void push(int tmp) {
    lck.lock();
    arr.push(tmp);
    lck.unlock();
    cv.notify_one();
}

int pop() {
    T x;
    lck.lock();
    while(arr.size() == 0)
        cv.wait(lck);
    x = arr.front();
    arr.pop();
    lck.unlock();
    return x;
}

int getCount() {
    T x;
    lck.lock();
    x = arr.size();
    lck.unlock();

    return x;
}
};
```

Error:

```
libc++abi.dylib: libc++abi.dylib: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
uncaught exception of type std::__1::system_error: unique_lock::lock: already locked:
Resource deadlock avoidedterminating with uncaught exception of type std::__1::system_error: 
unique_lock::lock: already locked: Resource deadlock avoidedlibc++abi.dylib: 
terminating with uncaught exception of type std::__1::system_error: unique_lock::lock: already locked: Resource deadlock avoided
```

Comment: `unique_lock`, as the name implies, is intended for use by only /one/ locking thread.   To lock from another thread, you need another lock.   The upshot of this - make `unique_lock` a local in each function, and not a class member.

Comment: I see a BIG PROBLEM: You lock your queue in your pop() method, and if it is empty you wait/loop until it has an element.. This cannot happen since you have it locked so push() cannot lock it to add. Never wait in between lock barriers. Also you should create the lock in the scope it is used so it will clean up when the scope exists even in exception cases, Or you could end up with t a lock that is nor released in exception cases.

Comment: @Rob - condition variable waits atomically begin the wait and /unlock the mutex protecting the condition/.  That part is OK, and is the standard usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment: unique_lock, as the name implies, is intended for use by only /one/ locking thread. To lock from another thread, you need another lock. The upshot of this - make unique_lock a local in each function, and not a class member.

```
template <typename T>
class MyQueue {
queue<T> arr;

mutex mtx;
condition_variable cv;
public:
MyQueue() {
}

void push(int tmp) {
    unique_lock<mutex> lck(mtx);
    arr.push(tmp);
    cv.notify_one();
    lck.unlock(); // Not nec'y, but polite...
}

...
```

and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

Consider deleting the `unique_lock` inside class, and changing your `push` and `pop` function to the following:

```
void push(int tmp)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lkg(mtx); // Here unique_lock not necessary.
    arr.push(tmp);
    cv.notify_one();
}

int pop()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ulk(mtx);
    cv.wait(ulk, [this]() { return arr.size() != 0; });

    auto x = arr.front();
    arr.pop();
    return x;
}
```

The reasons are very well explained in the comments :-).

You might also want to change your `mtx` to `mutable` if you want to provide `const` member functions like `empty()`; or copy constructor.